# Haskell Data.Type.Equality "Not in scope: data constructor ‘:~:’"

Tags: haskell

I am trying to use GADTs for the first time, and I wanted to implement variable substitution. Of course, I can only do the substitution if the types are equal. As I understand it, this should be possible using :~: from Data.Type.Equality. But somehow, the compiler doesn't want me to use :~: at all. To try it out, I wrote the following stupid function.

```
lol :: Int -> Int -> Bool
lol a b = case a :~: b of
  Refl -> True
  _    -> False
```

The compiler tells me:

```
Not in scope: data constructor ‘:~:’
```

I tried the following things:

- First, I thought, this is somehow an issue of having the wrong version installed. I saw that :=: is used in older versions. But :=: didn't work either.
- I changed the version for base in my cabal file explicitly to 4.8.1.0, still no luck.
- I copied the whole source code of Data.Type.Equality to a separate file called TypeEquality and imported it. Still the same error message.
- I thought it might be related to some extensions that I need to enable. I enabled all the extensions that Data.Type.Equality uses except for NoImplicitPrelude. Still no luck.
- I copied everything to the same file where I was using it. Still the same error message.
- I tried googling for other people using this module. I was unable to find anything useful. This would have been nice anyway since I don't really understand how to use it yet.
- I looked for other StackOverflow qustions with "not in scope". I didn't look through all of them, but it seemed like it was always related to uppercase/lowercase problems which doesn't seem to be a problem in my case.

After having tried out everything I thought of and being shortly before an emotional breakdown, I decided to ask the question here. Does anybody know what my problem could be? Probably you will need additional information to diagnose it, so please tell me anything I can provide. Since it is quite a big project, I didn't think providing the whole source code is useful...

## edit

Ok, it seems that I completely misunderstood the way :~: works. So I completely rephrase the question to what I actually need:

```
-- a is a variable symbol used for variable substitution.
-- b is a function symbol used for function substitution.
-- c represents a type of value that is contained.
data Ast a b c where
  BoolConst :: Bool -> Ast a b Bool
  IntConst :: Int -> Ast a b Int
  Var :: Eq a => a -> c -> Ast a b c
  -- Function application for a function with symbol b.
  App :: (Eq b, Eq c) => b -> Ast a b c -> Ast a b Int
  UnOp :: UnaryOperator c d -> Ast a b c -> Ast a b d
  BinOp :: BinaryOperator c d e -> Ast a b c -> Ast a b d -> Ast a b e
  NaryOp :: NaryOperator c -> [Ast a b c] -> Ast a b c
  Ite :: Ast a b Bool -> Ast a b c -> Ast a b c -> Ast a b c
```

I omitted the definitions of the operators, but you can imagine. First of all: As I understood it, it is impossible to implement functions with more  than one argument. So I implemented App as taking only one argument instead of a list and emulate multiple arguments by repeatedly applying it somehow. I still need to make some changes to make this work, but that is not the issue here.

Now I want to write two `substituteVar` and `substituteFunc` functions that substitute variables and functions. For simplicity, let's focus on `substituteVar` for now. I imagine to use the following signature:

```
substituteVar :: Eq a => M.Map a (Ast a b c) -> Ast a b d -> Ast a b d
```

The type parameters `c` and `d` are basically used as the return type. But I don't know how to handle the problem that Haskell doesn't "know" whether the type of the substitution `c` is the same as the type of a variable `d` that is encountered. So I thought I could somehow use `:~:` for that, but I guess I was wrong. Btw, I currently only need the types Bool and Int, but I want it to be extendible for more than that (but still a small number).

I am aware of the possiblity to use two constructurs for variables called `BoolVar` and `IntVar`. But while this is a bit ugly, but kind of works for variables, even if I extend it to 5 types, it would get really messy for the functions. I would basically need one type constructor every combination of argument and return type. Therefore, I thought that this solution doesn't scale and somehow it feels like there should be an easier possibility.

Comment: Did you `import Data.Type.Equality`?

Comment: Yes I did. And anyway, even if I didn't, it should have worked after I copied the source code to the same file where I wanted to use it.

Comment: `:~:` is a type operator - it operates on types, so `case a :~: b of ...` doesn't make any sense since `case ... of ...` works on terms.

Comment: Oh, ok. Then I completely misunderstood what :~: does. Ok. So I need to rethink a bit.

Comment: the syntax would be `case Refl :: (Int :~: Int) of Refl -> True` but this is not very useful since you can see here that `Int` and `Int` are the same! I very much doubt that you need `Data.Type.Equality` to do what you're trying to do; I think you should step back and ask a question about what you actually want to do (that problem that you believe `Data.Type.Equality` is the solution to)

Comment: This blog post appears to be a fairly good example of what `Data.Type.Equality` is for, although it was written before that module was incorporated and it has its own version called `PropEq` instead of `:~:` - https://typesandkinds.wordpress.com/2012/12/01/decidable-propositional-equality-in-haskell/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I completely rephrased my question now.

Comment: The correct type for `subst` is probably `M.Map a (Ast a b d) -> Ast a b d -> Ast a b d`. This way Haskell will "know" that the type variables are the same: you declare them as such.

Comment: No, that won't work. What you are proposing works for normal trees, but I am using GADTs here. The problem is that different subtrees have different types. For example, if I have two integer trees, I can use an equality binary operation to construct a boolean tree. The point is, the Haskell compiler cannot "know" in general that all variables have the same type since they can appear im different subtrees with different types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is by far my most stupid question on Stackoverflow. I would like to delete it, but maybe some day someone googles the same issue and is happy to see an answer, therefore I will answer it.

## Answer to my original question

I completely misunderstood the :~: operator. It works on types and not on terms, therefore my example makes no sense.

## About my second question

I don't have an answer, but I don't need it anymore. I like the idea of GADTs, but I was trying to apply it to something where they were just extremely hard to use. Possibly a more experienced Haskell programmer would have been able to use them properly in my context, but I am by no means a good Haskell programmer. So I will just use normal ADTs and give up some type safety, i.e. the compiler will not disallow a product of booleans etc. But in exchange, I can actually make it work.

Besides, it was a very bad style to completely change my question. Small adaptions are ok, but if the direction completely changes, I should have created a separate question with an appropriate title. The current state is just confusing for everyone who lands on this page. Besides, as a separate question with an appropriate title, I would have gad better chances to get a good answer.